# How can i get more values out of xml-svg file?

Tags: c#, xml

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class XmlReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum Rects
    {
        WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y, COLOR, ANGLE
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        ParseXml();
    }

    private void ParseXml()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

        var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new {
            Style = e.Attribute("fill").Value,
            Angle = e.Attribute("transform").Value,
            Width = e.Attribute("width").Value,
            Height = e.Attribute("height").Value,
            X = e.Attribute("x").Value
        });

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            string result = string.Format("Width: {0}, Height: {1}, X: {2}", item.Width, item.Height, item.X);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

The svg file format is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg"
   inkscape:export-filename="C:\Users\adili_000\Desktop\drawing.png"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="125"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="125">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="470.51389"
     inkscape:cy="692.09768"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid4172" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="37.387959"
       y="115.30345" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155-5"
       width="45.714287"
       height="30"
       x="91.899246"
       y="115.40621" />
    <rect
<path
       sodipodi:type="star"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#f1c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path4841"
       sodipodi:sides="8"
       sodipodi:cx="288.21429"
       sodipodi:cy="396.29076"
       sodipodi:r1="21.58555"
       sodipodi:r2="10.792775"
       sodipodi:arg1="1.0471976"
       sodipodi:arg2="1.4398967"
       inkscape:flatsided="false"
       inkscape:rounded="0"
       inkscape:randomized="0"
       d="m 299.00707,414.98441 -9.38404,-7.9932 -6.99549,10.1496 -0.98347,-12.28755 -12.12341,2.23029 7.99319,-9.38404 -10.1496,-6.99549 12.28756,-0.98347 -2.23029,-12.12341 9.38404,7.99319 6.99549,-10.1496 0.98347,12.28756 12.12341,-2.23029 -7.99319,9.38403 10.14959,6.99549 -12.28755,0.98348 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Some problems i can't yet figure out how to do.

First problem is how can i get the value of the fill of each rect fill i mean the color: style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill- So i need to get/extract the #00c8fc.

Another value is the 6 numbers of the transform some rects have transform in the bottom: I didn't add the whole content of the svg it's long but some rects in the bottom are:

```
<rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#00c8fc;fill-opacity:0.98823529;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4155-5-6-56-6-2"
       width="27.153143"
       height="13.716971"
       x="79.204071"
       y="477.30438"
       transform="matrix(0.9672488,-0.25383017,0.25383017,0.9672488,0,0)" />
```

And i need to get the 6 numbers: 0.9672488,-0.25383017,0.25383017,0.9672488,0,0

Update:

To get the style part i added the line:

```
Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(16,6),
```

Now how do i get the transform/matrix 6 numbers as 6 int variables ?
I need then to make some calculations with the 6 numbers.

The problem is that not every rect have transform in the bottom:
I tried to add the line:

```
Transform= e.Attribute("transform").Value.Substring(18, 43),
```

But getting null exception since not every rect have transform.

How can i extract this rect's that have transform the 6 numbers ? For example:

transform="matrix(0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0)"

So i need to get into 6 int variables the 6 numbers: 0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0

Comment: Your post contains multiple questions.  The preferred format for questions on stackoverflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  You might want to break the question down into simpler, indivisible pieces - you're more likely to get responses if you do.

Comment: I can get now the style and the fill value: Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(16,6), but how do i get now the 6 numbers of the transform of the matrix ? Not every rect have transform so sometimes i'm getting null exception. The line i added: Transform= e.Attribute("transform").Value.Substring(18, 43), but it's null since not every rect have transform. And still how do i get the 6 numbers ? For example: transform="matrix(0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0)" so i need to get 6 int's variables: 0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0

Comment: If there is no surity that every rect will have `transform` you should check for the null before applying string operation to it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i know but i don't know how to check for not null when using var list = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "rect").Select(e => new { how and where do i check for null ? I tried to add a if check but i can't add it inside there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used xml linq with regex and a dictionary.  Works real well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Rect.rectangles = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
            {
                style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
                height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
                x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
                y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
                transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? null : (object)Rect.GetTransform((string)x.Attribute("transform"))
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class Rect
    {
        public static List<Rect> rectangles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> style { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double? x { get; set; }
        public double? y { get; set; }
        public object transform { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetStyle(string styles)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
            string[] splitArray = styles.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Dictionary<string, string> style = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return style;
        }
        public static KeyValuePair<double, double> GetTransform(string matrix)
        {
            string pattern = @"[-+]?\d+\.\d+";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(matrix, pattern);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> kp = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(
                double.Parse(matches[0].Value),
                double.Parse(matches[0].Value)
                );

            return kp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed to accept null X as you asked in other posting

Comment: Sorry i missed your answer. The problem is how to check for null on the transform: Transform = e.Attribute("transform")?.Value i see in your answer you didn't add the Transform. The problem is i can't make ?.Value the x you are using is for the style but i need to check for null for the "transform". Some rects not all of them have the transform attribute: transform="matrix(0.40438612,-0.91458836,0.92071162,0.39024365,0,0)" that's why i need to check it for null.

Comment: I opened new question with a problem if you could take a look please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347790/how-can-i-parse-only-the-numbers-from-the-string thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> To get the style part i added the line:  Style = e.Attribute("style").Value.Substring(16,6),

This assumes that `fill` will starts at position 16, which may not be true for many reasons (e.g. *style="opacity:0.987;fill=..."*) and that value will be 6 characters long (incorrect for *style="opacity:1;fill=red;..."*). This should work much better:

```
Style = e.Attribute("style")?.Value.Split(';').Where(property => property.StartsWith("fill:")).Select(property => property.Substring(5)).FirstOrDefault(),
```

> So i need to get into 6 int variables the 6 numbers: 0.98125852,-0.1926959,0.1926959,0.98125852,0,0

Firstly, as these number are floating point numbers (not integers) you certainly need float or double variables. 
Secondly, to prevent exception when transform attribute is not present, use `?.` operator, that stops expression evaluation when value is null:

```
Angle = ParseTransformMatrix(e.Attribute("transform")?.Value),
```

and use this method to extract 6 transformation matrix parameters from attribute string:

```
static double[] ParseTransformMatrix(string transform)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(transform))
        return null;

    if (!(transform.StartsWith("matrix(") && transform.EndsWith(")")))
        return null;

    return transform
        .Substring(7, transform.Length - 8)
        .Split(',')
        .Select(s => Double.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Some people might prefer parsing such string using [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. But I don't personaly like it much.

Also please note, that my answer will only work for this particilar svg file, but might not work for other, because parsing svg file can be very complex task, when all possible features are taken into consideration (cascading of styles, some attributes can be set if several different ways, symbol instances, etc.)