# How can i parse only the numbers from the string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that in Rect.rectangles under the transform property instead to have the string "matrix(0.87142591,0.49052715,-0.49052715,0.87142591,0,0)" to have 2 properties like transform and transform1 and each one will have a number for example: transform "0.12345678"
         transform1 "1.12345678"

```
private void Parse()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");

        Rect.rectangles = document.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
        {
            style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
            id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
            width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            transform = x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43)) == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43))
        }).ToList();
    }
```

And the Rect class:

```
public class Rect
    {
        public static List<Rect> rectangles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> style { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double? x { get; set; }
        public double? y { get; set; }
        public string transform { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetStyle(string styles)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
            string[] splitArray = styles.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Dictionary<string, string> style = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return style;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use substring but getting out of range exception.

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot exceed length of string

On the line:

```
transform = x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43)) == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43))
```

The string is:

> transform="matrix(0.40438612,-0.91458836,0.92071162,0.39024365,0,0)"

And i want to get only the first two numbers: 0.40438612,-0.91458836

Update:

I found also a way to do it using foreach:

```
private void Parse()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");

        Rect.rectangles = document.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
        {
            style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
            id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
            width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform")
        }).ToList();
        string t = null;
        foreach(Rect rect in Rect.rectangles)
        {
            if (rect.transform != null && rect.transform != "")
            {
                t = rect.transform.Substring(7, 21);
            }
        }
    }
```

But i don't want to do it after the new Rect() {
I want to do the first two numbers extraction on the line:

```
transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform")
```

The reason is that i have in the bottom of the code a class:

```
public class Rect
    {
        public static List<Rect> rectangles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> style { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double? x { get; set; }
        public double? y { get; set; }
        public string transform { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetStyle(string styles)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
            string[] splitArray = styles.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Dictionary<string, string> style = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return style;
        }
    }
```

And i want that the property transform to hold/contain the two numbers already.

And another small problem how can i extract the first two numbers if for example one of the numbers have -(minus) in the start for example if transform contain the string: "matrix(0.40438612,-0.91458836,0.92071162,0.39024365,0,0)"

If one of the two numbers have minus in the start or both of them have minus in the start the Substring(7, 21) will not work. I need somehow to get in any case the first two numbers. But the main issue is how to extract the numbers directly from the attribute already.

Comment: In `"transform".Substring(18, 43)` you are trying to get a substring than starts in positiion 18 and has length 43, from the string `"transform"`, that has 9 characters length.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for *regular expressions*?

```
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ... 

 string transform = "matrix(0.40438612,-0.91458836,0.92071162,0.39024365,0,0)";

 double[] result = Regex
   .Matches(transform, @"-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Take(2)
   .Select(match => double.Parse(match.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: But how do i use it with the transform = x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43)) == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform".Substring(18, 43)) i want to do it on the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expression you can get the part of the string starting right after the first parenthesis and then split it using the comma:

```
var transform="matrix(0.40438612,-0.91458836,0.92071162,0.39024365,0,0)";
var numbers  = transform.Substring(transform.IndexOf('(') + 1).Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(numbers[0]));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(numbers[1]));
```

Please add error handling.

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DEh5k9)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
private void Parse()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\mysvg\Documents\my.svg");

        Rect.rectangles = document.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
        {
            style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
            id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
            width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
            x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
            transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? "" : (string)x.Attribute("transform")
        }).ToList();

        for(int i = 0; i < Rect.rectangles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Rect.rectangles[i].transform != null && Rect.rectangles[i].transform != "")
            {
                Rect.rectangles[i].transform = Rect.rectangles[i].transform.Substring(7, 21);
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Rect.rectangles = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "rect").Select(x => new Rect()
            {
                style = Rect.GetStyle((string)x.Attribute("style")),
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                width = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
                height = (double)x.Attribute("width"),
                x = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
                y = (double?)x.Attribute("width"),
                transform = x.Attribute("transform") == null ? null : (object)Rect.GetTransform((string)x.Attribute("transform"))
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
    public class Rect
    {
        public static List<Rect> rectangles { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> style { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
        public double height { get; set; }
        public double? x { get; set; }
        public double? y { get; set; }
        public object transform { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetStyle(string styles)
        {
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[^:]+):(?'value'.*)";
            string[] splitArray = styles.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Dictionary<string, string> style = splitArray.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Groups["name"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            return style;
        }
        public static KeyValuePair<double, double> GetTransform(string matrix)
        {
            string pattern = @"[-+]?\d+\.\d+";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(matrix, pattern);
            KeyValuePair<double, double> kp = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(
                double.Parse(matches[0].Value),
                double.Parse(matches[0].Value)
                );

            return kp;
        }
    }
}
```